# Customizing categories page

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a store in magento (tintinportintin.com.br) and I want to customize the categories page adding a specific color for each category page. For exemple I want that the same menu of home and all pages be blue in category x and red in category y. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The html body tag contain the  class name of each category, so one none programming way to do this, is to use css.

> `<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-pulseiras-casual-html category-casual">`
>
> `<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-colares-html category-colares">`

So in your style.css (you could add to the end)

```
.categorypath-colares-html #nav{
   background-color: black;
}

.categorypath-colares-html #nav a{
   color:red;
}

.categorypath-pulseiras-casual-html #nav a{
   color:blue;
}

.categorypath-pulseiras-casual-html #nav{
   background-color: black;
}
```

(The only limitation is if you change the category name, then you will need to update the css)

Comment: I should add this in the custom layout update box, in category management page?

Comment: I would add it to /skin/frontend/default/{local theme}/css/styles.css

Comment: You need to move the css above to the bottom of http://tintinportintin.com.br/skin/frontend/fortis/default/css/styles.css file or lookup the css `!important`

Comment: Now it's partially working. Look at tintinportintin.com.br/colares.html. The borders of #nav still doesn't change the color.

Comment: Take a look @ `.navbar-gray-d .navbar-bg` your using a background image.

Comment: I tried to change background image, but didn't worked. Look: tintinportintin.com.br/colares.html

Comment: Undo you last changes and do something like `.categorypath-pulseiras-casual-html .navbar-gray-d .navbar-bg{
background:none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The style.css in my store referring to #nav

```
   /* Classes specifying background and other settings for navigation bar */
.navbar {
    background-position:top left;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    float:left;
    width:944px; /* 944 = 960 - 2*8 */
    height:41px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.navbar-left {
    background-position:0 -51px;
    width:8px;
    height:51px;
    float:left;
}
.navbar-right {
    background-position:100% -51px;
    width:8px;
    height:51px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My style.css referring to the nav background:

```
.categorypath-colares-html #nav{
   background-color: #b7ea2c;
background:url(../images/img/navbar-lightgreen.png) no-repeat; 
}

.categorypath-colares-html #nav a{
   color:#b7ea2c;
}
```